# 365 PowerApps vs. Visual Studio (VB.net)

Tags: sql, vb.net, input, workflow, powerapps

For my small company I am trying to build a data input form for several departments that input data into SQL tables. I would like to give the user the ability to input data, update existing data, and see graphs of historical data that they have inputted.

I personally know VB.net but my IT head wants to use PowerApp. No one knows PowerApp in the company but he thinks it will be easier to use and implement/share across the company.

- Is PowerApp easy to learn?
- Can Power App input data into MS SQL?
- In general, which is better for my intended use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- YMMV, but in general PowerApps is easier than a programming-language based platform for building apps. It won't be as powerful as the latter, but for the specific example that you mentioned (data input, presentation), it should be fine. Take a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/#pivot=home&panel=maker), especially in the section about [creating an app automatically from your data](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/app-from-sharepoint) (the link talks about apps from SharePoint, but the same works for SQL Server as well)
- Yes, data integration is built in the platform, and SQL Server (both SQL Azure and on-premises installations of SQL Server) is supported
- As always, it depends (which is why this question may be closed for being primarily opinion-based). A full-fledged programming language will always have more power than a "no-code/low-code" solution such as PowerApps, but if what you need to do is within the domain of that solution, it will likely be easier to implement. PowerApps also makes it easier to deploy the app in mobile devices (iOS / Android), which is not as easy to do with VB.NET, but again, that depends on your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

We decided against using PowerApps as it would still require some coding and there is a larger support community for VB.net as well as Visual Studio is more robust.